# error: command 'i686-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installinin kivy

Tags: python, django, gcc, kivy

I tried to install kivy using pip.But the aforementioned error occurs.
Detailed error message is like this ,

```
Command "/home/rawdata/.virtualenvs/kivy/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-gWYerj/kivy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-aGOzJ1-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/rawdata/.virtualenvs/kivy/include/site/python2.7/kivy" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-gWYerj/kivy
```

I already have python-dev, libeven-dev, gevent etc installed.Same error occurs while installing cryptography and cffi.

could someone please find a solution.

FYI: I am using Linux mint 17.1 cinnamon.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem and this command saved me:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev
```